# cannot manipulate cassandra database node.js

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, cassandra

I am new in cassandra and I use apollo-cassandra as my orm. I connect the cassandra server with an external ip and already change the setting of rpc_address to public ip in cassandra.yaml. So far I can successfully connect to cassandra server with external ip. But I cannot save or query with database. I wonder what happened here. The following is my code.

```
apollo.connect(function(err){
 if(err) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log("cassandra connection failed");
}
else{
//my console will print "cassandra connection success". I think i can connect to it 
 console.log("cassandra connection success");
//add table schema
  var ChatLog = apollo.add_model('chatlog',chatLogSchema);
// create a new object
  var message = new ChatLog({
    uid: data.sender,
    time:data.time,
    msgid:data.msgid,
    sender:data.sender,
    receiver:data.receiver,
    group:data.grp,
    msgtype:data.msgtype,
    content:data.msg.message,
    bond_detail:null
});
//save the object to cassabdra
  message.save(function(err){
   if(err)
    console.log("cassandra save error");
   else
console.log("cassandra save success");
});
```

But no matter what I change my console still print "cassandra save error".

Is there anyone knows that what else did I miss?

Comment: It would be interesting to see what the variable err stores. Does the logfile show errors?

Comment: Can you add the code showing how you actually connect? I mean the part where you configure the IP you connect to, what port to use etc. (We don't need to know the ip specifically, just what params you are supplying)

Comment: I found the problem. Because I create the keyspace with the setting of 'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3.

But I didn't create other nodes in the cassandra.yaml. It can't manipulate the db.
The next problem is how to change the configuration to create nodes in cassandra. I have one data center and need more than one node to do the backup.
Is there any material or sample I can read?